# SaveDialog in Flex passes FileName and Path to Server Side C#

Tags: c#, apache-flex, savefiledialog

So I've got a flex project that runs on the desktop.  I've also got server side C# code that I run to export some data into a PDF when ever I click a button on the flex application.  Currently I just auto save the files to the temp folder inside of the C:\ directory, but I was wondering how I would go about opening up a Save File dialog box in Flex so I can select a location and name for my file and then pass the full file path string over to the server to do the exporting.  My research brought me to a "Filereference" class in Flex, however it looks like that actually saves some sort of file, where all I want to do is get the chosen file path from it.

EDIT: I'm working with a project that has both an Adobe AIR Application side and a Web Application side, both being run by common code, so it'd be best to have a method that is supported by both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you're building a Desktop application, I assume you are using Adobe AIR.  You can use the [File.browseForDirectory()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForDirectory%28%29) method.

Comment: I believe that could work, however the project I'm working in has both an AIR Application and Web Application that share common code, and File isn't accessible by web applications, so I would need a method that is supported by both web applications and AIR applications

Comment: There isn't one.  You can't do this a in browser based application.  A Browser Based application cannot save files to a user's local machine without user input.

Comment: hm, that raises issues.  It looks like my best bet is to either A) Find a way to do this PDF creation on the flex side, or B) find a way to send the file created on server side back to flex and then save it through FileReference.save(), and the more I look at it the more I'm thinking B isn't a valid option

Comment: FileReference.save() requires user interaction. It would work but not in an automated fashion.  Creating the PDF in Flex will not get around this limitation.

Comment: so you're saying that even if I created the PDF in flex/managed to get it from c# server to flex client, I could use FileReference.save to save it, but there would be something I'd have to do to get it to work?

Comment: Yes, in a browser based application user interaction will be required to save the file.  The user has to click a button to bring up the "FileReference.save()" window.

Comment: Alright, well basically my current idea now is to make a service call when the user presses a button, this will start a function on the server that will create the file onto the server and pass back a connection url, that will then be used in flex with FileReference.download().  Is there an easy way to get that connection string to download the file? I was thinking Server.MapPath might get me what I need, but I'd like to do it in a way where I avoid making a useless pop up window show up

Comment: I'm not quite sure; you'll have to test and see.